# Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have two questions.

1) In phpmyadmin each time I log in it gives this error

> Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

2) I'm trying to register an html form to the database but i got this warning says:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

### The Code:

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
    mysql_select_db("bookaride"); 
?>
```

### Edit:

```
/* Authentication type and info */ 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'; 
// Authentication method (config, http or cookie based) 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true; 
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Comment: #2 - obviously you're using the wrong credentials, but since you've shown no code, we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry here is my databade connection <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("bookaride");

?>

Comment: @jamane Please edit your question to contain the code.

Comment: well, obviously your root account either doesn't have access (very unusual), or you haven't provided the required password. that's not something we can help you with.

Comment: @jamane you need a password of root user

Comment: any example how to set the password?

Comment: /* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';      // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

Comment: jamane, you really need to [edit] your question each time, not comment with that stuff

Answer (score 0):

Open you Mysql console, if you are using WAMP should be here (C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin) or something like that

After you open the console, enter this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bookaride TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Try to run your script again

Comment: if root doesn't already have those privileges, he's in trouble for a bit

Comment: I'm using XAMPP. I wanted to put the php code but stackoverflow tells that some is wrong in the code i cant post it .

Comment: @Drew I tought that too but I don't know how his database it is, so it might be worth trying.

Comment: well how would he connect with root to issue it :>  Just to point out, he is dying in source code on the connect, not db change, not queries. Just having fun Raf

Comment: @jamane Try to do this: `$cn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); $db = mysql_select_db('bookaride', $cn)` and see what happens

Comment: When i try the one you sent Raf Zeres it gives thisWarning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Ok, lets try something else. Reset your root password. Here's how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Beware the use of PHP "`mysql`" functions, it's [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) since Dec/12 and will be soon **removed**. You better chose from `mysqli` like

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
```

or `PDO`, like

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bookaride", 'root', '');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

unless you're using an older version of PHP.

**2)** Your error implies your credentials are wrong. You can **try** to reset your root credentials following [these instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).